# How Update table if ... else

Tags: php, mysql

I want update table, but something goes wrong. How can I update my table if something is TRUE or NOT. For example if it is true I want set value 0, if not increase +1. Here my code:

```
$fp = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
            if ($fp) { 
                print "<TR><TD>$idt</TD><TD>$name<TD>OK</TD><TD>$quantity</TD></TR>\n";
            } else { 
             print "<TR><TD>$idt</TD><TD>$name<TD>Error</TD><TD>$quantity</TD></TR>\n";
                }

if ($conn->query($fp) == TRUE) {
    $resetsql = "UPDATE addresses SET count=0";
} else {
   $updatesql = "UPDATE addresses SET count=count+1";
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking the value of `$fp`, you want to run a query and check it's result.

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `CASE`:

```
UPDATE addresses SET cnt = CASE WHEN :param = 1 THEN 0 ELSE cnt + 1 END
```

If `:param` is `1`, then `0` will be assigned to `cnt`. Else, `cnt` is incremented.

In MysQL this can shortened as:

```
UPDATE addresses SET cnt = CASE WHEN :param THEN 0 ELSE cnt + 1 END
```

Comment: Maybe OP looks for `execute()` or something like that also?

Comment: Maybe something simplier?

Comment: @xyz91: this gives you a simple query that gets the job done at once, instead of implementing the logic in your application. You just need to provide the query with a `0/1` value...

Comment: I found something like that: UPDATE table SET ( failuretime=NOW(), count=count+1 )
UPDATE table SET ( failuretime=null, count=0 ) How to use it

Comment: Ok I try it. Should I paste like that? if ($conn->query($fp) == TRUE) {
    $resetsql = "UPDATE addresses SET cnt = CASE WHEN :param THEN 0 ELSE cnt + 1 END";